# Java 8 Lambda Not working?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

Hi I have this (what i assume to be) really trivial code:

```
List<Integer> f = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    Collections.sort(f, (Integer f1, Integer f2) -> {
        Integer.compare(f1,f2);
    });
```

However, I get the following compile-error:

> Cannot convert from `Comparator<Integer>` to `Comparator<? super T>`

This isn't very helpful - what is going wrong?

Comment: This is the place for the almost mandatory reference to [“When to use LinkedList over ArrayList?”](http://stackoverflow.com/q/322715/2711488) as everyone using `LinkedList` most likely haven’t read it…

Comment: I don't always use Lists, but when I do I use Vector

Comment: You should always use `List`s, where appropriate. But prefer `ArrayList`. There is almost never a reason for `LinkedList` [nor `Vector`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1386275/2711488).

Comment: @bharal if you prefer/use Vectors, then you need to read this (I did too and learned !) : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386275/why-is-java-vector-class-considered-obsolete-or-deprecated

Comment: @Holger everyone here is *very* serious, no?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use method reference in this case:

```
 List<Integer> f = new LinkedList<>();
 Collections.sort(f, Integer::compare);
```

In the original code there is missing return statement:

```
 Collections.sort(f, (f1 ,  f2) -> {
        return Integer.compare(f1,f2);
 });
```

***return*** must be used if lambda contains `{}`

Same thing without return and brackets:

```
Collections.sort(f, (f1 ,  f2) -> 
         Integer.compare(f1,f2)
);
```

A few useful notes from comments section below:

It is possible to just use `Collections.sort(f)` and rely on natural ordering.  by [Jean-François Savard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2683146/jean-fran%C3%A7ois-savard)

Since Java 8 `List` interface has `sort` method which can also be used `f.sort(null); f.sort(Comparator.naturalOrder());` or, `Collections.sort(f, Comparator.naturalOrder());` by [Holger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2711488/holger)

Comment: Um, but what if i just wanted to do it how i did it - is that impossible? What am i doing wrong? Thanks for the answer, but it doesn't answer my question!

Comment: thanks so much, i didn't realise i'd messed up the return {} stuff, good to know.

Comment: @bharal I updated my original answer, but the shortest way is to use method reference.

Comment: Thanks again - i didn't even know they existed! I asked for the clarification just because the actual problem isn't sorting Integers, i just simplified it down (hence the desire for the full method, not your initial answer(

Comment: You could simply do Collections.sort(f) and rely on natural ordering.

Comment: Or `f.sort(null);`. Alternatively, `f.sort(Comparator.naturalOrder());` or, `Collections.sort(f, Comparator.naturalOrder());` will do as well.